# Find actual data size from a query?

Tags: t-sql, size

Is it possible to find the size of data that will be returned by a particular query?

For example, I can use the following to find the number of rows per date:

```
select mydatecolumn, count(*) 
from MyTable
where mydatecolumn < '01-JAN-2014'
group by mydatecolumn
```

But is there a way to find out the size of the data that is contained in those rows?

e.g.

```
select mydatecolumn, "sizeofactualdata",
from mytable
where mydatecolumn < '01-JAN-2014'
group by mydatecolumn
```

Even if it's one query per date that's not a problem.

Comment: "Size" is not a property of "data".

Comment: I think you need to ask "How to calculate the Result Set data size ?"

Comment: Probably a better way of putting it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way of **How to calculate the Result Set data size**

If using  Management Studio:
**Go to Menu >> Query >> Include Client Statistics** 
[image]

**Once you enable the client statistics, it will display another tab in the result span; when clicked, we obtain the following:**
[image]

As shown in the image, it will capture details for different trials and they are compared with each other. Green arrows indicate improved statistics and red arrows indicate degrading statistics. Please note that here an increase does not always imply a good result; sometimes some statistics when marked as “up” can imply a bad result as well. For the same reason, they are colored in green and red, signifying good and bad results, respectively.